# var.get() variable in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing code by python tkinter and everything in the code is seems alright except var.get() which python can't define it at all. IntVar() function holds integer data where we can set integer data and can retrieve them.

here is my code:::

```
'''
Created on 29 Oct 2022

@author: musta
'''

import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *



Trn   = tk.IntVar()
Intr  = tk.IntVar()
Total = tk.IntVar()
var   = tk.IntVar()

def Sum():
     if var.get() == 1:
        Qty1 = float(Trn.get())
        Qty2 = float(Intr.get())
        Sumup = Qty1 - (Qty2)*1.387439/41
        Total.set(Sumup)
def Rest():
    Trn.set("0")
    Intr.set("0")
```

Comment: var is not defined in your provided code. Please provide a [mre] in order to get help.

Comment: to add to @Thingamabobs... you never call `Sum` either. That's why there is no error. Maybe you don't know that `configure` accepts `**kwargs`. Your code is absolutely bloated with `configure` calls and it makes it very hard to read.

Comment: sorry about that, it seems that python can't read 'var = tk.IntVar()'

Comment: Even you have updated your code, but it is still not a [mre]. Also it is better to provide the full traceback as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this example will help?

```
import tkinter as tk
 
root = tk.Tk()
 
int_var = tk.IntVar(root, value = 255)
 
num = int_var.get()
 
print(num)
```

Output: 255